# testContainers Initialization Error with java.lang.InterruptedException

Tags: java, docker-compose, testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5

I am having this error running Quarkus tests with docker-compose, upgrading from Quarkus 2.4.0 to Quarkus 2.15.0, not sure why it is happening, but if anybody can shed some light it will be helpful.

It happens running integration tests, it sounds like it is timing out, so I tried to put a higher timeout value

```
quarkus.devservices.timeout=180
```

but it did not work either.

```
[2022-12-19T08:55:14.576Z] > Task :score-integrationtest:test
[2022-12-19T08:55:14.576Z]     2022-12-19 08:55:12,293 WARN  [org.ecl.jet.ser.AbstractConnector] (pool-2-thread-1) Acceptors should be <= availableProcessors: NetworkTrafficServerConnector@161ff9e6{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1, h2c)}{0.0.0.0:0}
[2022-12-19T08:55:14.576Z]     2022-12-19 08:55:12,720 INFO  [org.ecl.jet.ser.Server] (pool-2-thread-1) jetty-9.4.49.v20220914; built: 2022-09-14T01:07:36.601Z; git: 4231a3b2e4cb8548a412a789936d640a97b1aa0a; jvm 17.0.1+12-LTS
[2022-12-19T08:55:14.576Z]     2022-12-19 08:55:12,803 INFO  [org.ecl.jet.ser.han.ContextHandler] (pool-2-thread-1) Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@64f54045{/__admin,null,AVAILABLE}
[2022-12-19T08:55:14.576Z]     2022-12-19 08:55:12,848 INFO  [org.ecl.jet.ser.han.Con.ROOT] (pool-2-thread-1) RequestHandlerClass from context returned com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.StubRequestHandler. Normalized mapped under returned 'null'
[2022-12-19T08:55:14.576Z]     2022-12-19 08:55:12,856 INFO  [org.ecl.jet.ser.han.ContextHandler] (pool-2-thread-1) Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5e9f3de4{/,null,AVAILABLE}
[2022-12-19T08:55:14.576Z]     2022-12-19 08:55:12,876 INFO  [org.ecl.jet.ser.AbstractConnector] (pool-2-thread-1) Started NetworkTrafficServerConnector@161ff9e6{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1, h2c)}{0.0.0.0:9701}
[2022-12-19T08:55:14.576Z]     2022-12-19 08:55:12,877 INFO  [org.ecl.jet.ser.Server] (pool-2-thread-1) Started @30367ms
...
[2022-12-19T08:55:16.123Z]     2022-12-19 08:55:15,908 INFO  [ .5]] (agroal-11) Creating container for image: postgres:14.5
[2022-12-19T08:55:16.423Z]     2022-12-19 08:55:16,106 INFO  [ .5]] (agroal-11) Container postgres:14.5 is starting: 3225b3d78588be4297362f627043c39b27ddf5b1dd71438e153b2b5b4d07fc29
[2022-12-19T08:55:21.997Z]     2022-12-19 08:55:20,933 ERROR [ .5]] (agroal-11) Could not start container: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InterruptedException
[2022-12-19T08:55:21.997Z]      at org.testcontainers.containers.output.WaitingConsumer.waitUntil(WaitingConsumer.java:105)
[2022-12-19T08:55:21.997Z]      at org.testcontainers.containers.output.WaitingConsumer.waitUntil(WaitingConsumer.java:78)
[2022-12-19T08:55:21.997Z]      at org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.LogMessageWaitStrategy.waitUntilReady(LogMessageWaitStrategy.java:45)
[2022-12-19T08:55:21.997Z]      at org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.AbstractWaitStrategy.waitUntilReady(AbstractWaitStrategy.java:52)
[2022-12-19T08:55:21.997Z]      at org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer.waitUntilContainerStarted(PostgreSQLContainer.java:143)
[2022-12-19T08:55:21.997Z]      at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:485)
[2022-12-19T08:55:21.997Z]      at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:344)
[2022-12-19T08:55:21.997Z]      at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:81)
[2022-12-19T08:55:21.997Z]      at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:334)
[2022-12-19T08:55:21.997Z]      at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:322)
[2022-12-19T08:55:21.997Z]      at org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver.connect(ContainerDatabaseDriver.java:124)
[2022-12-19T08:55:21.997Z]      at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:226)
[2022-12-19T08:55:21.997Z]      at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:535)
[2022-12-19T08:55:21.997Z]      at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:516)
[2022-12-19T08:55:21.997Z]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[2022-12-19T08:55:21.997Z]      at io.agroal.pool.util.PriorityScheduledExecutor.beforeExecute(PriorityScheduledExecutor.java:75)
[2022-12-19T08:55:21.997Z]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
[2022-12-19T08:55:21.997Z]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
[2022-12-19T08:55:21.997Z]      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[2022-12-19T08:55:21.997Z]     Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
[2022-12-19T08:55:21.997Z]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1679)
[2022-12-19T08:55:21.997Z]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.pollLast(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:533)
[2022-12-19T08:55:21.997Z]      at org.testcontainers.containers.output.WaitingConsumer.waitUntil(WaitingConsumer.java:85)
[2022-12-19T08:55:21.997Z]      ... 18 more
```

Comment: Have you tried to check the postgres docker container logs before the exception appears and while the container is still running?

Comment: When Testcontainers fails the wait strategy of a container, it logs the container logs. Please share those.